# Does an AirPort access point as bridge allow communication between Macs?

Tags: mac, network, airport, time-capsule, file-transfer

I am planning to make this network :

```
  ⎡ Internet modem ⎤      ⎡    AirPort     ⎤ <--> [ PC ]     
  ⎢       &        ⎥ <--> ⎢  access point  ⎥                 
  ⎢     router     ⎥      ⎢   as bridge    ⎥ <⋅⋅> [ Mac 1 ]  
  ⎣   (Freebox)    ⎦      ⎣ (Time Capsule) ⎦ <⋅⋅> [ Mac 2 ]
```

The AirPort (wi-fi) access point will be connected to the router in (gigabit) Ethernet.

I am interested in the wi-fi communications between the Macs.

Let’s say I send a big file from Mac 1 to Mac 2.

[Alas, the Macs have to send and receive the waves through the access point.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110882/do-the-wi-fi-communications-from-mac-to-mac-travel-through-the-access-point)

Is this long enough, or do the communications have to go through the router too ?

Comment: To connect the Time Capsule to the Freebox (router), in which port of the Time Capsule do I plug the cable ? WAN or LAN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will be sent through the Time Capsule, but not through your Freebox.

Mac 1 will attempt to send a file to Mac 2 by sending it to the Time Capsule where it is directed to to Mac 2. The data won't go through the Freebox unless an internet connection is required for this data to be sent.

Comment: I like this answer. But it is sure ? Are you a specialist in networks, @grgarside ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco As sure as I can be! I'm no networking specialist, but based on the fact that I have an extremely similar setup with full root device access to both my router and modem, I'm able to tell that when I send a file from one Mac to the other the data rate increases for the AP but not the modem.

Comment: The DHCP server will be the Freebox.